# making a cube with color coded cells in r

Tags: r

I want to make a cube with color coded cells based on the data clustering information.
I found a code on here using cube3D to make the cube but I do not know how to incorporate the cells into the cube. I have included a sample cube I found:

[image: sample picture of a cube]

Comment: It looks like you're fairly new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample code you've attempted, listing non-base R packages, any errors/warnings received, and sample data, like the output from `dput(head(dataObject)))`. Check out these resources for great questions: [making R questions reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269) and [tagging questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.